# Is it still possible to connect to Astra DB using DataStax Studio?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra

Developer Studio used to available on the Astra web UI which provided a notebook-like interface for interacting with the database.

It looks like it is no longer part of the Astra Dashboard. Is it still possible to connect to Astra DB using DataStax Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of user feedback, [**DataStax Studio**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/studio/docs/aboutStudio.html) is no longer included in the Astra web UI dashboard but **Studio** is available to download for free from the [DataStax Downloads](https://downloads.datastax.com/#studio) site.

Once you've downloaded either the Windows or MacOS/Linux version of the package, follow the [instructions to install Studio](https://docs.datastax.com/en/installing/docs/installStudio.html) on your laptop or workstation. Then [start the Studio server](https://docs.datastax.com/en/studio/docs/studioStartStop.html). It is ready when you see the following line on the console:

```
Studio is now running at: http://127.0.0.1:9091
```

To connect to your Astra DB, you will need the following:

- Client ID + secret of your [application token](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/manage/org/managing-org.html#_manage_application_tokens)
- [secure connect bundle](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/connect/secure-connect-bundle.html) (zip file containing DB connection details + SSL/TLS certificates)

**STEP 1** - Access Studio on your laptop/workstation by browsing to http://127.0.0.1:9091.

**STEP 2** - Click on the "hamburger" icon in the top-left corner of the page to open the Main Menu then select **Connections**.

**STEP 2** - Click the ➕ (plus) icon to create a new connection.

**STEP 3** - Click on the **Astra Connection** tab and fill in the following fields:

- **Name** - name the connection, usually the Astra DB name
- **Secure Connection Bundle path** - `/full/path/to/secure-connect-db.zip`
- **Client ID** - from your application token
- **Client Secret** - from your application token

**STEP 4** - Click on the **Test** button to validate the credentials then hit **Save**.

You should now be able to create a new notebook (or upload an existing one) to interact with your Astra DB. Cheers!